# Can't insert flexslider into my website. Jquery interference

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to insert flexslider 2 into my website and it doesn't work properly. I've tried to setup the slider on a separate blank site, and it worked.

I see that the flexslider uses jquery 1.6.2, while my website is already running vers. 3.1.0 so i'm guessing they are interfering with each other. If i try to just use the 1.6.2 version my website obviously doesn't function properly however if i try to just use 3.1.0 version the slider dont work. What can i do?

Comment: I ran into issues with 3.1.0 and jquery ui.  I ended up backing out and going to a  previous version.  Unfortunately, its been a while and I cant remember the exact nature of the problem

Comment: Found a solutiuon for use of multiple jQuery versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1566644/6817961